# tomcat context.xml split into entities

Tags: tomcat, netbeans, xml-parsing, context.xml

We are developing a web application using Windows 8.1, NetBeans 8.02 and tomcat 8.0.15. We have our context.xml in web/META-INF. As it is getting bigger and bigger, it would be nice to split it into parts and using XML entities to include the parts into the main context.xml.

According to this post:
http://blogs.mulesoft.org/including-files-into-tomcats-server-xml-using-xml-entity-includes/
this is possible.

So based on this, I have tried:

context.xml:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE Context [
<!ENTITY imports SYSTEM "imports.cnt">
]>
<Context ...>
  ...
  &imports;
  ...
</Context>
```

where imports.ent is placed in web/META-INF besides context.xml and contains some Resource nodes that were originally subnodes of the Context node.

However, this is not working from NetBeans, it seems that the problem is that imports.cnt is not found because upon deployment imports.ent is not placed into 
C:\Users\nora\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.0.2\apache-tomcat-8.0.15.0_base\conf\Catalina\localhost
and the deployed context.xml in this directory looks like this:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE Context [<!ENTITY imports UNKNOWN>]>
<Context ...>
  ...
</Context>
```

So tomcat is complaining because the context.xml is not parsable:

```html
SEVERE [http-nio-8084-exec-12] org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processContextConfig Parse error in context.xml for /CarManagement
 org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/C:/Users/nora/AppData/Roaming/NetBeans/8.0.2/apache-tomcat-8.0.15.0_base/conf/Catalina/localhost/CarManagement.xml; lineNumber: 2; columnNumber: 38; OpenQuoteMissingInDecl
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:203)
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:177)
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:441)
```

Even placing imports.cnt there manually does not help.

**How to tell NetBeans that imports.cnt should be preprocessed and deployed together with context.xml?**
The file imports.cnt is not even listed among the Configuration files of the webapp and I do not know how to add it there.

I have also tried using the war file without NetBeans:
copied the war under tomcat webapps dir and then it is working BUT:
I had to copy imports.cnt both under tomcat bin directory and under conf/Catalina/localhost.

Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance.